# Can not copy cisco packet tracer icon

Tags: icons, cp

```
$ cp PacketTracer.jpeg /usr/share/icons/
cp: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/share/icons/PacketTracer.jpeg’: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 2):

`/usr/share/icons/` directory is owned by `root` and only owner has the write permission:

```
drwxr-xr-x   19 root root  4096 Feb 10 00:14 icons
```

So, any normal user can not copy any file into that directory. You need to use `sudo`:

```
sudo cp PacketTracer.jpeg /usr/share/icons/
```

Comment: sir i want to creat icon of packet tracer i cant see its icon when i use packet tracer i always open through terminal .. please help me . what can i do . so that the icon of packet tracer can seen that area where firefox , settings are present

Comment: Hello @ShahidKhan, Welcome to Askubuntu. This is a different question that what your original question was about. Please ask it as a [new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).

Comment: thanks sir but i follow one  video i do same thing that video show me ... but i face problim when when i am typing commands at terminal . i successfull open packet tracer .. but after that i am unable to creat icon of packet tracer ...http://openpy.com/installing-and-running-packettracer-in-all-version-of-linux/

Comment: @ShahidKhan: Use the command i have given to pass this step and go to the next, then try to follow the video again.

Comment: drwxr-xr-x: command not found

Comment: @ShahidKhan: The command is `sudo cp PacketTracer.jpeg /usr/share/icons/`

Comment: okk now  i face another problim there :/usr/share/applications$

Comment: @ShahidKhan: Your original issue has been resolved, if you have any further issues please ask it as a [new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).